# detect keypress event for all textboxes inside a nested TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, events, loops, controls

I have a series of nested `TableLayoutPanel`controls which each of them contains lots of `TextBox` controls.

I think it is insane to make a keypress event for each of the textboxes, So what I am trying to do is to have a common event method and then apply the event for all textboxes on `FormLoad` event. What I want to do is to see if the user has pressed `Enter` key in any of those textboxes.

This is my common method (I hope nothing is wrong with it!):

```
private void ApplyFiltersOnEnterKey(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        tsApplyFilters_Click(this, null);
    }
}
```

And I have the following code in  `Load` event of my form:

```
    //Applying common event for all textboxes in filter options!
foreach (var control in tableCriterias.Controls)
{
    var textBox = control as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
        textBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.ApplyFiltersOnEnterKey);
}
```

Well, maybe you can guess already, the codes above does not work! I can list the problems I can think of:

- `tableCriterias` which is the parent `TableLayoutPanel` and all the other layout panels are inside it, is itself inside a series of `Panel` `SplitContainer` and....Do I need to point this in my loop?
- Or do I recursively loop over each layoutpanel inside the main layoutpanel?
- Or the whole idea is wrong?!!?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void Recursive(TableLayoutPanel tableCriterias)
{
    foreach (var control in tableCriterias.Controls)
    {
        var textBox = control as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
            textBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.ApplyFiltersOnEnterKey);
        else if(control is TableLayoutPanel)
            Recursive(control as TableLayoutPanel);
    } 
}
```

And call this method for **parent** TableLayoutPanel